Question on installing NEMA 14-50 for EV charging
I have a question with regard to installing a NEMA 14-50 for EV charging. I know these outlets are not fantastic for this purpose, but I’m looking to install one just temporarily to be replaced by a hardwired or plugged dedicated wall unit.
My family bought an older house recently, which has been remarkably well maintained. I have a 40A non-GFCI breaker in my 200A panel in the basement, which was intended for an oven (in the basement? I know, right?).
To accommodate that connection the previous owners put in 3/4” RMC with three (I think) 8 gauge copper wires (may actually be 6, haven’t measured them) and one thinner (aluminium?) wire hooked up to a 14-30R over a distance between 60 to 70ft.
I’ve unhooked that receptacle to repurpose the wiring and hook up a NEMA 14-50 receptacle on the outside of my house. The RMC is still entirely inside the house structure. I sealed off the hole with duct seal, caulked the receptacle—-pretty sure no moisture will get in. They’re real stiff wires to work with, encased in rubber and then paper-like wrapping, both in excellent condition: one white, one black and one red. White is obviously neutral, and the other two L1 and L2.
My question: there’s a thinner (I suspect) aluminium wire in that same RMC, which I’m pretty sure is to ground the receptacle (I have seen it elsewhere in the house). Can I just use that same wire to ground the socket itself? As in, run a piece of wire from the socket under the green ground screw to the screw in my receptacle to hook up the socket to the same ground?
I have seen plenty of folks ask about hooking these things up, but haven’t yet found anyone discuss the thin aluminium wire (it’s not plated copper).
I can add a photo if that’s useful. FYI: I do have experience with this kind of thing abroad, just not with slightly older cable in the US on the east coast.
Thanks y’all!

Can you get us the diameter of the thinner wire, and is it a bare wire or insulated?  Also, are we talking about a continuous RMC run?

The receptacle also needs to be Al/Cu rated.  The receptacle also needs GFCI protection(breaker) in most places if to be passed by an inspector.  Why hard wired is recommended.

@ThreePhaseEel: the thinner wire is bare and quite thin in comparison, I would say 10 or 12 gauge? The RMC is continuous from the breaker box all the way to the wall outlet (approx. 60-70ft).

@crip659: I think the receptacle is fine. I know nowadays these need a GFCI breaker though the ev charger unit has one built in and I don’t want them to conflict. When I swap out the outlet for a hardwire setup I’ll replace the breaker too. Thanks for the reminder though!

You can ignore the wire or land it on a ground screw in the box, then ground the receptacle to the box
Since you have a continuous run of RMC from the panel to the outlet, that's your equipment grounding conductor, and the extra aluminum? wire is superfluous.  Do what you will with the extra wire, and simply use a 10AWG copper pigtail to ground the receptacle to the box, presuming that you're using a metal box that is.
Since you have conduit, if you don't mind redoing the run...
Since that run in conduit, if your panel is listed and labeled for Eaton BR breakers and has 2 extra spaces in it, then you could replace the thin aluminum wire and one of the copper wires with a 18/2 tray cable, then install an Eaton EVCI into the panel and a junction box kit at the outdoor location.  This gives you a J1772 cable coming out of the wallbox without the need for extra parts, as all the EV charging smarts are in the branch circuit breaker itself.

excellent, thanks for the clarification; I hooked it all up correctly then. I had heard about the RMC being ground as well, but I’m not used to conduit to be used in that way. Anyway, I did add the Al? wire as ground on the metql box and did ground the receptacle onto the box; I guess one can never ‘overground’ the circuit. Thanks again!

just out of curiosity, the second setup you describe, with the 18/2, would also effectively avoid GFCI conflicts, correct? I do like the idea of having all that logic in-house, rather than a 14-50, though I also like the idea of being able to just unplug and swap out my wall unit if only that part would die not to mention the ‘smart’ options that come with different wall units (looking at Emporia Level 2 currently)

@MartinUildriks -- the setup with the EVCI would avoid all GFCI conflicts, yes, because the EVCI packs all the EVSE logic into a double-frame circuit breaker :)

Very good with the EVCI.  Based on conversations with Coul St., I see that as the way things are going.  It puts the GFCI protection at the origin of the circuit, and it minimizes the tech that is out at the pedestal. Very important if the pedestal is prone to getting hit by a drunk driver. Also combines very well with "untethered", which J3400 introduces to this country.
